# cohort analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have spent the whole weekend trying to figure out if there is an analytics tool that will support my app requirement for intelligent cohort analysis on active-customer/customer-retention, but frustratingly I have not found anything. I can't believe that I am the only one trying to monitor this type of data so I assume that I am missing the point and therefore open to suggestion on where to focus my efforts...

I need to track numbers of active users in my app. I define an **active** user as someone who has used it (even if only to view data) in the last 90 days. If a user does not access the app for more than 90 days then they become an **in-active** and they can stay inactive for a further 90 days. At the end of the 90 days they become **dormant** and I assume that they have decided not to use my app or found an alternative. However, if the return at any time then the "clock" is reset and they become active again.

So to sum up in point form:
Active User - anyone who is using my app regularly.
In-active User - someone who has not accessed/viewed/used the app for the last 90 to 180 days.
Dormant User - someone who has not accessed/viewed/used my app for more or greater than 180 days.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could implement this either by writing my own custom code or preferably by using an analytics tool kit like Flurry or Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a field on your users table that says the last time they logged in it should be simple enough to query that data using SQL to get the report you want. Based on your definition of cohort that seems to be the best way to get the data you want.

The problem about getting this data through a Web Analytics platform is that these platforms usually track things that happen on the site, while your definition is for something that doesn't happen to trigger a state change.

Both [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/) and [Kissmetrics](http://www.kissmetrics.com/) support some kind of cohort analysis. Even though it's not exactly what you defined it might be close enough or possible to emulate your use case.

Google Analytics doesn't provide cohort analysis out of the box, you could try to emulate that with custom variables, but I think that might be a little more complicated than the other options.

Answer (score 0):

I have been aggregating a list of various solutions for app developers here at [AppSDKs.com](http://www.appsdks.com/) including a category for [analytics](http://www.appsdks.com/?category_id=1).  Hope this helps.